# Two Dimension System with plotting coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, plot

I have plot that I need to draw in latex however I am having hard time to plot using latex.  I have started the plot bit I am not able to label all the quadrant and do the projection. Please see the attached picture

[image]

Here is the code I start it if you can help me finish it or suggest better way.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb,amscd,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [thick, ->] (0,-5) -- (0,5);
  \draw [thick, ->] (-5,0) -- (5,0);
  \node [above] at (0,5) {$\theta_2$};
  \node [right] at (5,0) {$\theta_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=stealth,bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
  \draw [->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node [above] {$\theta_2$};
  \draw [->] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node [right] {$\theta_1$};
  \draw [densely dotted, ->] (-3,3) node[bullet,label=left:$X$]{}-- (0,3) node [right] 
  {$\widetilde{\theta}$};
  \draw [densely dotted, ->] (3,-3) node[bullet,label=below:$X$]{}-- (3,0) node
  [above]   {$\widetilde{\theta}$};
  \draw [densely dotted, ->] (-3,-3) node[bullet,label=below left:$X$]{}-- (0,0);
  \path (4,4) node{$Q_1$} (-4,4) node{$Q_2$} (-4,-2) node{$Q_3$} (4,-2) node{$Q_4$}
   (3,3) node[bullet,label=right:{$X=\widetilde{\theta}$}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, Is it possible to add X = theta in the first quadrant

Comment: @JesZ I added it.